# rails ajax call redirect to invalid path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/posts/product_list.json',
    data: {sub_cat_id: parseNumber(sub_category_id)},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //$('#selection').show();
        $('#selection').html(data.html);
    },
    error: function(data){
    }
});
```

I have the post_list controller

```
respond_to :json,only: :product_list
      def product_list
        @products = Product.where(sub_category_id: params[:sub_cat_id])
        ##blah blah blah
      end
```

My url is showing like this while inspecting `product_list.json?sub_cat_id=5`

But the debugger is showing `request parameter` as follows

```
{"sub_cat_id"=>"5", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"posts", "id"=>"product_list", "format"=>"json"}
```

I am very much confused why this is happening can any one clear it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you manually submitting ajax over using Rails' "remote" options?

Comment: @RichPeck It is not a form. The selection is based on list of categories

Comment: Okay, so you're binding to the form's "change" function or something? It's always helpful to know the whole story, that's all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you don't have a corresponding route entry. You should have something like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts do
  get :product_list, on: :collection
end
```

If you only specify `resources :posts`, your GET request would match the one for `GET /posts/:id` (look at the output of `rake routes`), i.e. `show` action of `PostsController` with `product_list` parsed as the id parameter in the request URI. `get :product_list` defined after those 7 entries would make the router match the URI to the corresponding action and controller.

Comment: It is working but i can't understand why i need to mention it in route